# I need to write Macro in c for assembly language commands

Tags: c, assembly, macros

I have written this macro to add assembly language commands in C:

```
TEST_ASM(asm_command)  asm( #asm_Command )
```

which works perfectly for single commands like:

```
TEST_ASM("nop")
TEST_ASM("write 0")
```

But, for this:

```
TEST_ASM("e_li r3, 0x201")
```

It gives error:

> macro "TEST_ASM" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1 for

This error is due to the comma in `asm` command which looks for the next argument.

Could it be possible that macro take comma as string?

I don't want to use variable argument macro as it will give warnings in static analysis.

Comment: What compiler do you use? Would you mind providing fully [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates "good" and "bad" behavior?

Comment: @yeputons He uses "asm", which is a GNU extension, in his answer, so I'm assuming gcc or something compatible.

Comment: @yeputons  I use above macro for variety of compilers like cosmic ghs

Comment: Something to think about when trying to write code like this (from the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html)): *Do not expect a sequence of asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation. If certain instructions need to remain consecutive in the output, put them in a single multi-instruction asm statement. Note that GCC’s optimizers can move asm statements relative to other code, including across jumps.*  BTW, a multi-instruction asm might look like `mov eax, 1\nmov ebx, 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use stringification in macro, following snippet works for me on gcc:

```
#define TEST_ASM(asm_Command) asm( asm_Command )

int main()
{
  TEST_ASM("mov $1,%eax");
  return 0;
}
```